# C# Multiple values for single argument

Tags: c#, arguments, console-application

I'm just learning C#, I've made a console application that accepts command line arguments, but I need an argument that accepts more than one value and puts them into a string array.

Here is what I have so far, in case it isn't obvious, the argument -colors should be able to accept multiple values and put them in their own array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    switch (args[i])
    {
        case "-dob":
            birth = args[i + 1];
            birthDay = Convert.ToDateTime(birth);
            break;

        case "-name":
            name = args[i + 1];
            break;

        case "-colors":
    }
}
```

Comment: Show an example of how do you plan to pass these parameters to your program through a command line

Comment: Expanding on @Steve's question - it's usually simplest to use a delimiter and just split on that, e.g. "Red|Green|Yellow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple values as color and add them internaly to a list

```
List<string> colors = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    switch (args[i])
    {
        case "-color":
            colors.Add(args[i + 1]);
        break;

    }
}
```

and you will use it as

> myProgram.exe -color red -color blue

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the values with a specific character and then make split by the character. For example red.black.white  and then

```
var array= args[i + 1].Split('.')
```